# python replace any number of spaces in line with single comma

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file of lines like this:

```
a    b c d e
```

Using python 3.8 I want to replace spaces to produce this

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

I have this :

```
lines = [line.replace(' ', ",") for line in open("abc.txt")]
```

But this produces a,,,,b,c,d,e.

Ideally I can modify this line of code with a single tweak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
','.join(line.split())
```

will get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you for not using a regex. :)